# Slurm multifactor priority - how to configure Slurm to consider past usage?

Tags: linux, priority, slurm

I'm trying to configure our Slurm to allocate users' jobs according to past usage.
The goal is to have the job priority consider past time usage of mainly GPUs.
I understand I must use the FairShare tree to configure its weight, but I'm not sure how to configure for Fairshare what variables to consider. I just don't seems to get the gist of how this is supposed to work.

Current configuration is:

```
###Job Priority##
#Fair tree, multifactor with its parameters (http://slurm.schedmd.com/fair_tree.html)
#PriorityFlags=FAIR_TREE
#PriorityType=priority/multifactor
#PriorityDecayHalfLife=14-0
#PriorityMaxAge=7-0
#PriorityUsageResetPeriod=NONE
#PriorityWeightAge=100
#PriorityWeightFairshare=10000
#Unused weights
#PriorityWeightJobSize=0
#PriorityWeightPartition=0
#PriorityWeightQOS=0
```

Possible configuration (correct me if I'm wrong):

```
###Job Priority##
#Fair tree, multifactor with its parameters (http://slurm.schedmd.com/fair_tree.html)
PriorityType=priority/multifactor
#PriorityDecayHalfLife=14-0 PriorityMaxAge=7-0  PriorityWeightAge=1000 PriorityWeightFairshare=10000
#Unused weights PriorityWeightJobSize=100 PriorityWeightPartition=0 PriorityWeightQOS=0

PriorityUsageResetPeriod=MONTHLY

AccountingStorageTRES=gres/gpu,gres/gpu:geforce_rtx_1080,gres/gpu:titan,gres/gpu:quadro,gres/gpu:geforce_rtx_3090,gres/gpu:v100
TRESBillingWeights="CPU=1.0,Mem=0.25G,gres/gpu=1.0"
```

Would this do the trick? Change the weights for TRESBilling?

Thanks to those who would answer!